# Imagick not reflects the gravity once it is set

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert, imaging

I am trying to translate the following piece of Imagemagick command line code

```
 convert tmpI.mpc -gravity center -crop ${ww}x${hc}+0+0 +repage
```

as follows

```
$tmpIC->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$tmpIC->cropImage($ww, $hc, 0, 0);
$tmpIC->setImagePage($tmpIC->getImageWidth(), $tmpIC->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);
```

but setting or not setting the gravity makes no difference. Please tell me what is wrong with the piece of code I have

Width and Height of the image before cropping are

```
tmpIC->getImageWidth() = 479
tmpIC->getImageHeight() = 599
```

And the values of ww and hc are

```
ww=479
hc=479
```

and the width and height of the image after cropping are as follows

```
tmpIC->getImageWidth() = 479
tmpIC->getImageHeight() = 479
```

Comment: Does the `convert` command you suggest work on the command-line? Try resetting the page (with `+repage`) **before** cropping as well.

Comment: Yes, the convert command works perfectly. Also, I tried to reset the page (+repage) before cropping but no difference

Comment: What are the dimensions of the starting image? What are the values of `$ww` and `$hc`? What do `$tmpIC->getImageWidth()` and `$tmpIC->getImageHeight()` return after cropping. Please click `edit` under your question and update the information there rather than in comments. Thanks.

Comment: updated the question. please check

Comment: And the starting image?

Comment: Updated the starting image width and height too

Comment: I do not think Imagick cropImage supports gravity settings. If you look at the cropImage page there is an example that show that for each gravity setting, the code computes the equivalent offsets from the top left corner. Anyone who knows Imagick well can correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: Just found this as a solution. Use cropThumbnailImage. It will crop in the center and scale at the same time. So set the scale to 100 so that it does not reduce the image size. See http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php

Comment: But it won't work for NortEast, SouthWest and so on right?

Comment: That is correct. It is only for gravity center. For other gravity settings, you would have to compute the equivalent offset relative to northwest (top left) corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the ImageMagick commands can be converted directly to the same named commands in Imagick.

In your case, the gravity command doesn't map very well - but the same effect of cropping the image to the centre can be done by yourself in a single cropImage function call:

```
$tmpIC->cropImage(
    $ww,
    $hc,
    $startX = ($tmpIC->getImageWidth() - $ww) / 2,
    $startY = ($tmpIC->getImageHeight() - $hc) / 2
);
```