# Translate Imagemagick command to Imagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following imagemagick command line options

```
-gravity center -background none -extent ${wbg}x${hbg}
```

which I replicated with the following Imagick code piece but not producing the same result.

```
$tmpA12->setImageGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

$tmpA12->setImageBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel("transparent"));

$tmpA12->extentImage($wbg, $hbg, 0,0);
```

I believe the setImageGravity is not acting upon the image or the offset 0,0 needs the right value. I am bit stuck here please help me on it

Comment: My guess is that extentImage, like cropImage, does not support gravity settings. You will have to compute the center offset from the northwest corner, like you have to in cropImage and use the x,y offsets built into extentImage. However, before you give up on gravity, try http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setgravity.php (setGravity) rather than setImageGravity.

Comment: setGravity doesn't work either. Could you give me some tips on computing the offset from the northwest to the image area

Comment: See the switch code at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php. The same offsets for cropping apply to extentImage.

Comment: er - you asked a really similar question about 2 weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740417/imagick-not-reflects-the-gravity-once-it-is-set The answer is also going to be similar.

Comment: Yes. I just figured out that the extendImage works as cropImage. I still just wonder, why the setImageGravity function is not making an effect. Does it have a different usage?